# run job file via ssh command order how?

Tags: ssh, cron, backup

about run script.sh via ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpbackup
clamscan -i -r --remove /home/
exit
```

are that mean run  /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpbackup and after finished run  clamscan -i -r --remove /home/

or run two command at same time ???

Answer (score 2):

Commands in a script are run one at a time in order unless any of the commands ["daemonizes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) itself.

Comment: you mean clamscan -i -r --remove /home/ will run after backup or with backup ?

Comment: It will run after, unless `cpbackup` daemonizes itself.

Comment: i try it today , i see that two command run at same time , can any one help how to do it after it